# How to access a node file from nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

So, I have the following file:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var mustache = require('mustache');

var view = {
    title: "Joe",
    calc: function() {
        return 2 + 4;
    }
};

var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";

var html = mustache.to_html(template, view);

sys.puts(html);
```

when I run it with node `nodejs mypage.js` I get the following output:

```
Joe spends 6
```

That is all great! My question now is, how would I access this through Nginx?

So, for example `http://example.com/mypage.js`

**Edit**

Here is the Nginx config (**Note** I am using `jsp` instead of `js` since `js` is already taken as a file extension):

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com;

    location ~ \.jsp$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/nginx.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Hitting the page gives me a `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: Interesting... So you want nginx to just run the command, and then respond with the output? This seems like a funky way to accomplish what you're trying to do. It's actually pretty difficult in nginx to run oldschool cgi scripts. You can use a `HttpLuaModule` to run a command I guess.

Comment: I am currently running Nginx on the server with php-fpm, I thought it would be cool to try it with node instead, so I assumed that I could do it in a similar way...

Answer (score 3):

i know it's not what you asked for, but here's the most basic way to do it in node. if you want to build a node server the go-to standard is [express](http://expressjs.com)

```
var sys = require('sys');
var mustache = require('mustache');

function handleRequest(req, res){
  var view = {
      title: "Joe",
      calc: function() {
          return 2 + 4;
      }
  };

  var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";

  var html = mustache.to_html(template, view);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end(html);
}

var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest):
server.listen(3000, function(err){
  console.log(err || 'Server listening on 3000');
})
```

Comment: Maybe because I am still new to node, this is better, but how would this work if say I had 100+ pages? I wouldn't want to write all those pages in this one file, or edit this server file every time I added a new page to the site.

Comment: @Plato gave the first half of the answer- i.e. he gave you a server to respond to your request(+1). Now what you need is an nginx.conf file to set up nginx as your reverse proxy- this basically means to set it up to listen on a specific port, and route requests to node. Which OS do you use? Can you put up a copy of your nginx.conf file on pastebin?

Comment: @Goran_Mandic see my revised question with the nginx config

Comment: If you had 100+ pages you would definitely want to use Express or find some other framework! It's a bitch to set all this up manually for every URL!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to configuring nginx as a reverse proxy, but this is how I did it on my local machine. I have some static files (images, css, etc.) that I want to be served by nginx because it's much faster at doing that, and for all other `GET` and `POST` requests, it forwards them to Node.

I didn't quite get what you wanted to be served by nginx, and what you wanted Node to do, but here goes..

Open your nginx.conf file and try setting up your `http` block, and the `server` block inside it to look something like this:

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  #keepalive_timeout  0;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
  } 
  server {
     listen       80;
     #if localhost doesn't work, try 127.0.0.1 !!!
     server_name  localhost;

     location / {
        #note the port number below! You'll have to enter the 
        #port that Node uses!! (it's usually 3000)
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
     }  


    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

This tells nginx to forward GET requests from 127.0.0.1:80 to 127.0.0.1:3000.
Now, let's say you had an `img` folder where you store your images and you want nginx to serve these, instead of node (which is a VERY common scenario), you'd want another `location` block inside your `server` block.. it would look something like this:

```
location /img {
# /yourProjectLocation folder should contain the img folder-
# if not, then go down until you reach the containing subfolder:
# /yourProjectLocation/subfolder1/sub2/......./folderContainingImg;
        root   /yourProjectLocation;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

This will handle all the `GET /img/myPic.jpg` requests instead of forwarding them to node.

You might want to consider rephrasing your question title to something broader, to help people google-ing for a similar issue.

Comment: Okay, I did it a little differently. My `location /` has this: `try_files $uri /media/images/default.gif;` and my `location ~ \.jsp$ {` has the proxy information.